# Finding the range of frequencies to which a receiver should be set

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, frequency

I'm working on a study guide for a test for my Modern Physics class, and ran across a question I'm having trouble with.

> A radar transmitter emits a pulse of EM radiation with
>   $\lambda=0.225\,\mathrm{nm}$. The pulses have a duration of $1.17 \mu
> s$. The receiver is set up to accept a range of frequencies about the
>   central frequency. To what range of frequencies should the receiver be
>   set?

This is giving me more trouble than I'd like. I'm not really asking for a solution to copy (since it's just a study guide) but really more of a "plan of attack" if you will, or a walk-through so I can apply the reasoning to other problems of the sort.

What equation do I use to calculate the range of frequencies? The typical wave equation? Am I thinking too simplistically?

Thanks.

Comment: An X-ray Radar? At such a TX frequency and such a long pulse the receiver acceptance bandwidth will be determined by the expected range of Doppler to be accommodated rather than anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea involved here is this: EM radiation of a pure, single wavelength of, say, λ=0.225nm is an infinitely long wave that lasts from a time of negative infinity to positive infinity. If you Fourier analyze such an infinitely long wave, the wave breaks down to just a wave with a wavelength of λ=0.225nm and zero contribution from waves of all other wavelengths.

On the other hand, if you Fourier analyze a pulse with a wavelength of λ=0.225nm that lasts only 1.17μs, you'll find that it doesn't break down to just an infinitely long pulse with λ=0.225nm that lasts from a time of negative infinity to positive infinity. Rather, you'll find that there are waves of many other wavelengths clustered around λ=0.225nm that also have to be added to the "pure" λ=0.225nm wave in order to sum up to a pulse with a wavelength of λ=0.225nm that lasts only 1.17μs. Your study guide is basically asking for the range of frequencies associated with all of these other wavelengths that are required to form the EM pulse that you described.

Comment: is it possible to use the uncertainty relations $\Delta\omega\Delta t \approx 1$ or $\Delta k \Delta x \approx 1$ to find the range?

Comment: Well, yes, if you don't want to go through the fun of actually doing the Fourier transform, you can simply note that (as mentioned by many information sources describing Fourier transforms) the width of a pulse in frequency space is inversely proportional to the with of the same pulse in time space. Same thing with distance versus wavenumber spaces.

Comment: So I could calculate it this way: ∆f=[2π∆t]^-1? Since $\omega=2\pi f$

Comment: Yes, you can use that equation.